# Unknown reason behind out_of_range error for substring

Tags: c++

UPDATE: Yes, answered and solved. I also then managed to find the issue with the output that was the real problem I was having. I had thought the substring error was behind it, but I was wrong, as when that had been fixed, the output issue persisted. I found that it was a simple mix up in the calculations. I had been subtracting 726 instead of 762. I could've had this done hours ago... Lulz. That's all I can say... Lulz.

I am teaching myself C++ (with the tutorial from their website). I have jumped ahead time to time when I have needed to do something I cannot with what I have learned so far. Additionally, I wrote this relatively quickly. So, if my code looks inelegant or otherwise unacceptable at a professional level, please do excuse that for now. My only current purpose is to get this question answered.

This program takes each line of a text file I have. Note that the text file's lines look like this:

.123.456.789

It has 366 lines. The program I first wrote to deal with this had me input each of the three numbers for each line manually. As I'm sure you can imagine, that was extremely inefficient. This program's purpose is to take each number out of the text file and perform functions and output the results to another text file. It does this per line until it reaches the end of the file.

I have read up more on what could cause this error, but I cannot find the cause of it in my case. Here is the bit of the code that I believe to contain the cause of the problem:

```
int main()
{
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
    double d;
    double e;
    string search; //The string for lines fetched from the text file
    string conversion;
    string searcha; //Characters 1-3 of search are inserted to this string.
    string searchb; //Characters 5-7 of search are inserted to this string.
    string searchc; //Characters 9-11 of search are inserted to this string.
    string subsearch; //Used with the substring to fetch individual characters.
    string empty;

    fstream convfil;
    convfil.open("/home/user/Documents/MPrograms/filename.txt", ios::in);
    if (convfil.is_open())
    {
        while (convfil.good())
        {
            getline(convfil,search); //Fetch line from text file
            searcha = empty;
            searchb = empty;
            searchc = empty;

            /*From here to the end seems to be the problem.
              I provided code from the beginning of the program
              to make sure that if I were erring earlier in the code,
              someone would be able to catch that.*/

            for (int i=1; i<4; ++i)
            {
                subsearch = search.substr(i,1);
                searcha.insert(searcha.length(),subsearch);
                a = atof(searcha.c_str());
            }
            for (int i=5; i<8; ++i)
            {
                subsearch = search.substr(i,1);
                searchb.insert(searchb.length(),subsearch);
                b = atof(searchb.c_str());
            }
            for (int i=9; i<search.length(); ++i)
            {
                subsearch = search.substr(i,1);
                searchc.insert(searchc.length(),subsearch);
                c = atof(searchc.c_str());
            }
```

I usually teach myself how to get around these issues when they come up by looking at references and problems other people may have had, but I couldn't find anything that helped me in this instance. I have tried numerous variations upon this, but as the issue has something to do with the substring and I couldn't get rid of the substring in any of these variations, all returned the same error and the same result in the output file.

Comment: I think `searcha += subsearch` is a bit easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem:

```
    while (convfil.good()) {
        getline(convfil,search); //Fetch line from text file
```

You test for failure before you do the operation that can fail.  When `getline` does fail, you're already inside the loop.

As a result, your code tries to process an invalid record at the end.

Instead try

```
    while (getline(convfil,search)) {   //Fetch line from text file
```

or even

```
    while (getline(convfil,search) && search.length() > 9) {
```

which will also stop without error if there's a blank line at the end of the file.

Comment: Yes, that seems to have gotten rid of the problem I mentioned above. Now I'm faced with a different problem, as the output remains the same. Now that I know the substring isn't the cause of the issue with the output, I will be able to more easily locate _that_ issue. Thank you!

Comment: @4rkain3: If this was the solution to your problem, to the left of my answer is an outline of a checkmark.  If you click it, it will turn green to indicate an "accepted answer" and let future visitors know it was right.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you are reading a blank line at the end of the file and trying to process it.

Test for an empty string before processing it.